# How to call the Accounts and Sync settings page in android With a button click?

Tags: android

I tried the following:

```
Intent intent=new  Intent(Settings.ACTION_SYNC_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
```

However it does not work with Jelly Bean, is there a replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android documentation has some great stuff on the different Settings screens and how to get to them through intent calls. That can be viewed [right here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html).

I think what your looking for is:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ADD_ACCOUNT));
```

Comment: Actually I want the user to hit Sync, The above code however will do and hey I am following on the link you gave and thanks a ton for the same, keep on coding :)

Comment: This would be the intent for calling the Sync Settings: Intent intent = new  Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SYNC_SETTINGS);
   startActivity(intent);